# ifstream fin load error

Tags: c++, file, visual-studio-2012, x86-64

I am trying to load a file, but am not able to fetch it. Here is the command..

```
void Apple::loadDictionary(std::vector<std::string>& ret)
{
  std::ifstream fin("words");
  if(!fin.good()){
    return;
  }
  while(!fin.eof()){
    char buffer[4096];
    fin.getline(buffer, 4096);
    std::string curr(buffer);
    ret.push_back(curr);
  }
  fin.close();
}
```

I have added the file called words into the Visual Studio Project. Right Click on Project Name and Add Existing Item and selecting the words file. Let me know if this is the error.

The fin doesnt load the string making the condition `!fin.good()` as true and program terminates. Need some help on this.

Do I need to use any #include in this ??

Comment: Are you sure the programs working directory is the same as the one where the file is? See the project/solution properties to check/set the working directory.

Comment: Also, you appear to be loading a file without an extension. Is it not 'words.txt' or something like that?

Comment: No.. Its just a words file with no extension.. There are around 1 million words with one word per line..

Comment: also `while(!fin.eof())`?? Why not `while(fin.getline(buffer, 4096))` instead?

Comment: I havnt reached till there... I want to first load the file, later I can think of what to do once the handle is set up.. I have all the files in same directory..

Comment: Check which directory the executable is running in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds as if you have not copied the file to the project directory, by just adding it using *Add Existing* to the project does not automatically copy the physical file to your project directory it just adds a link to it.

Instead copy the file to your project dir first then do *Add Existing* or if you want the file to remain in place use an absolute path to it in your program.

Note also that the "folders" in the project do not have to be physical folders on the drive but should be more seen as filters. e.g. "*Header Files*"

Comment: I added the "words" file to all the sub-folders inside the Project Folder and its working !! Thanks everyone for helping me with this...